# Dual boot on Macbook Pro retina with REFInd

Tags: boot, dual-boot, macbook, refind

I recently tried to dual boot my 2013 Macbook Pro Retina with Ubuntu. I was able to install Ubuntu and REFInd without a problem but now my computer boots to Ubuntu by default. When REFInd starts it doesn't show me my install of OS X, instead it only presents me with options for Ubuntu and the OS X recovery partition. My OS X install is still present and I can boot into it if I hold down option key on boot (that only presents me with Macintosh HD) so I'm pretty sure its some issue with the way REFInd is configured. How do I make it so REFInd can see my OS X install so I can choose to boot into either OS.

Also how do I make OS X my default OS? I read that I can do it from OS X but in the startup disk, it only shows my Mac HD and has it selected for the start up disk.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I haven't been able to find anything online about this issue.

Comment: See my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/853919/refind-not-working-on-dual-boot-macos-ubuntu/930361#930361

Answer (score 0):

Change the timeout value in the `refind.conf` configuration file. With a value of `-1` rEFInd boots directly, with a value of `0`, it waits indefinitely. A positive value set the waiting time in seconds.

From the [rEFInd documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html):

> Thus, the rEFInd configuration file might be /boot/efi/EFI/refind/refind.conf, /boot/EFI/BOOT/refind.conf, /Volumes/ESP/EFI/refind/refind.conf, S:\EFI\refind\refind.conf, or something else, depending on your OS and mount point.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the "recovery" option in rEFInd is booting the OS X recovery system? For reasons best known to Apple, they decided to install their *non-recovery* boot loader on a partition called `Recovery HD` in recent versions of OS X, so it shows up that way in rEFInd's menu, on the first row. There may also be a second-row icon that launches the actual recovery image.

If you're really not seeing an entry in rEFInd, then it may have been accidentally removed by edits to `refind.conf` -- say, the `dont_scan_dirs` option or something similar. I recommend you check those. Try restoring the default `refind.conf` file (called `refind.conf-sample` in the rEFInd package) and see if that helps.

As to setting the default, you can do that with the `default_selection` option in the `refind.conf` file -- at least, if you're talking about the default OS in rEFInd.